# Matrix product including skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices

Consider the following real matrix

$M:=Jxkx^\top J^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

where $J\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is skew-symmetric, $k\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. It turns out, via software calculation, that this matrix always has a zero eigenvalue, independently from the (positive) value of $k$. Can anyone provide a proof (or at least an explanation) of this?

Comment: You mean that you ran a few tests and each time it had a zero eigenvalue, or you were able to show that for any $n$, and any appropriate entries, it has a zero eigenvalue?

Comment: Since $M = k(Jx)(Jx)^T$ is an $n\times n$ rank-one matrix it is not full rank and hence always has a zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Which is the consideration that allows to claim that M is rank-one? Which properties of skew symmetric matrices have to be used to prove it?

Comment: @dave I meant that I ran a few tests..

Comment: @Daniele The matrix $M$ is the outer product of the vector $Jx$ with itself, hence it has rank one. It doesn't matter that $J$ is skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

If $n=1$, since $J$ is skew-symmetric, $J=0$, hence the eigenvalue is $0$.

If $n>1$,

$$M=k(Jx)(Jx)^T$$
(credit: K. Miller)

Note that $Jx \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, hence $rank(Jx) \leq 1$, hence $rank(M) \leq rank(Jx) =1$. and hence the $nullity(M)>1$.

Hence one of the eigenvalue is $0$.